# aws elasticbeanstalk nodejs console.log does not appear in web.stdout.log

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS ElasticBeanstalk (AMI2) to setup my nodejs server,

I found that when I use console.log to print some log, it do appear in /var/log/web.stdout.log

But, when I write too many log in one minute, it stop writing to web.stdout.log until next minute.

I haven't suffer such king of problem in old AWS ElasticBeanstalk (AMI1). Do I need to

config rsyslog ?

Comment: I tried to add $SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0 in /etc/rsyslog.conf, but seems not work

Comment: seems I should change $OmitLocalLogging on => $OmitLocalLogging off in /etc/rsyslogd.conf  or  upload a file to replace /etc/systemd/journald.conf

But this is not so easy achieve from upload file by  .ebextension or .platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day struggle, I finally fix this problem.

put a .platform/systemd/jounrald.conf file in my zip file.

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See journald.conf(5) for details.

[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
RateLimitInterval=3s
RateLimitBurst=30000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
```

with another postdeploy script

.platform/hooks/postdeploy/update_journal.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cp /var/app/current/.platform/systemd/journald.conf /etc/systemd/journald.conf
service systemd-journald restart
```